# Injecting routes programmatically into a JSX router switch statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-router-v4

I've been trying to inject some `JSX` routes into a router switch statement without success. 
Basically I'm trying to be able to reuse the method `commonRoutes` for different scenarios so I do not have to repeat myself...
However when I inject the routes as illustrated the routing does not behave as expected and multiple routes will trigger at the same time instead of conditionally...
hopefully the code illustrates clearly what I'm trying to do:

First try:

```
class App extends Component {
  commonRoutes() {
    return (
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/route1" component={Component1} />,
        <Route path="/route2" component={Component2} />,
        <Route path="/route3" component={Component3} />,
      </Switch>
    );
  }

  app() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Header />
        <div className="app-content">
          <Switch>
            <Redirect exact from="/" to="/folder" />,
            {this.commonRoutes()},
            <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
        <Footer />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }

  render() {
    let content = '';

    if (this.props.component === ComponentList.COMPONENT_APP) {
      return this.appFrame(this.app());
    } 

    if(this.props.component === ComponentList.COMPONENT_FOLDER) {
      return this.appFrame(this.folder());
    } 

    if (this.props.component === ComponentList.COMPONENT_EVENT) {
      return this.appFrame(this.event());
    }

    return content;
  }

  appFrame(content) {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <CssBaseline/>
        <NotSupported  support={[{ name: 'ie', minSupport: 11 }]}/>
        <Favicon url={`${AppConfig.CONTEXT}favicon.ico`}/>
        <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          {content}
        </MuiThemeProvider>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
  //... code
}
```

Second try:

```
class App extends Component {
  commonRoutes() {
    return [
      <Route path="/route1" component={Component1} />,
      <Route path="/route2" component={Component2} />,
      <Route path="/route3" component={Component3} />
    ];
  }

  app() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Header />
        <div className="app-content">
          <Switch>
            <Redirect exact from="/" to="/folder" />,
              {this.commonRoutes()},
            <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
        <Footer />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Another way that comes to mind is using an object with keys to store the JSX routes and looping with `map`, but several attempts did not do the trick either.

I appreciate any help or direction.

Comment: the render function does the following `return this.appFrame(this.app());`
`appFrame` returns the content wrapped in a few common JSX directives

Comment: just aded that part of the code thanks

Comment: It  just doesn't work as expected and there are no errors, all the routes render and the switch statement gets ignored. Also the commas between the routes render, which is interesting...

Comment: no joy same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing,

```
let content = ''
if (...) {
  return this.appFrame(this.app());
} 
...
return content
```

The preceding code works but not the way you expect. You're trying to return the content after the condition is matched. This just return the `this.appFrame(...)`.

```
let content = ''
if (...) {
  content = this.appFrame(this.app());
} 
...
return content
```

Now, this works the way you're expecting. It assigns the value to the `content` and finally return the `content`.

Now, to your issue, you should be using `exact` props to return only the required component:

```
commonRoutes() {
    return (
      [
        <Route exact path="/route1" component={Component1} />,
        <Route exact path="/route2" component={Component2} />,
        <Route exact path="/route3" component={Component3} />
      ]
    );
  }
```

Also, ensure to use unique `key` when you render array of elements. In your case, it is `[<Route key={'unique-key'} />,...]`.

And also remove path from here:

```
<Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
{/* -----^^ not required react router 4 */}
```

Comment: Thank you I did actually try this at first (did not mention it sorry), and when I do I get very strange behaviour as if the switch statement broke by doing that, and all the commas in the switch get rendered instead, as if all the routes rendered... and the switch was ignored

Comment: it did thanks... react asked me to add a key attribute to each array element, that's all. It works thanks!